# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^k|a_ib_i|c_i\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|^pc_i\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k|b_i|^qc_i\right)^{1/q}$, where $c_1,...c_k >0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I know that this immediately follows from Holder's inequality if all the $c_i=1$, and I take $\mu$ as the lebesgue measure and define $f(x)=\sum a_i I_{[i-1,i)}(x)$, $g(x)=\sum b_i I_{[i-1,i)}(x)$. But I'm not sure how to handle the $c_i$'s.

Is there perhaps some way to show that $$\int|fg|h\leq\left(\int|f|^ph\right)^{1/p}\left(\int|g|^qh\right)^{1/q}$$

if $h>0$, and $f\in L^p,g\in L^q$?

Maybe some well known identity/inequality that would help push the initial problem further, or perhaps some intuition that would help me think of it problem more clearly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does considering the measure $\mu$ over $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ given by $\mu(i)=c_i$ sound?

Comment: Sounds too good to be true.

Are there any nasty details to be weary of? I've over-learned a fear of solutions that seem too straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the usual Holder's inequality applied to $(a_ic^{1/p})$ and $(b_ic^{1/q})$.

Comment: Ahh. You're right.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For $p>0$, $q>0$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ by Holder we obtain:
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^k|a_i|^pc_i\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k|b_i|^qc_i\right)^{1/q}\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\left(|a_i|\cdot c_i^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot|b_i|\cdot c_i^{\frac{1}{q}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}=\sum_{i=1}^k|a_ib_i|.$$
Actually. The Holder's inequality it's the following.

> let $a_i$, $b_i$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive numbers, $n\geq1$ be an integer number. Prove that:
> $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^{\alpha}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^{\beta}\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_i^{\alpha}b_i^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}\right)^{\alpha+\beta}.$$